# Iterate through List and pick right value using Drools

Tags: java, drools

So I have a list of objects like this

```
public class BesPeople{
  List<person>
}

public class person{
  int height;
  int weight;
  int shoesize;
  String votingRecord;
}
```

if I input a list into drools of lets say of 5 people, and i want to pick the best person of those five based on business rules, how would I do that in drools?  Its not quite clear that is possible. All examples I have seen have been on what to do based on a single object.

I could just write a stream().filter() and get the right person that way, but that would be logic that is embedded in the source and I am looking to eventually pull some of our complex business logic out of our source and give our business more control over it.

If what I am doing doesn't make any sense, Ill just blow it all away and write some complex filter logic for it.

Comment: Using Drools and a Rete rules engine to pick a value out of a list is crazy.  A JDK 8 filter will do the job much more simply.  Is the list large?  Do you really need a classifier?

Comment: The list can be large ish (maybe a couple of hundred).  Not out of this world though

Comment: our problem is we are expecting this list of rules to grow in the future.  I guess embedding it in the code is good job security in these uncertain times :D

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you'd do is pick a person and then verify that there's no "better" person.

As an example, let's say we want to find the tallest person, so we'll leverage your `height` property. (I'm going to assume that your person object has a `getHeight` method. I'm also going to assume that there's a `getPeople()` method in BesPeople since you neglected to even name that variable in the example.)

```
rule "Find tallest person"
when
  BesPeople( $ppl: people )
  $p: Person($h: height) from $ppl
  not(Person( height > $h ) from $ppl)
then
  // $p is the tallest, do whatever you want with them here
end
```

Basically, the rule does the following:

- We get a Person from the list and assign them to the variable `$p`. We've assigned the variable `$h` to that chosen person's height.
- We verify that there does not exist another person in the list whose height is greater than the value `$h`
- Thus, the value `$p` refers to the tallest person once you get to the "then" clause / right hand side.

This is obviously a very simple example, but you didn't exactly define 'best' in your question. If your "best" condition is more complicated, you might end up having multiple rules and write "fall-through" scenarios, for example. If you have a specific (more complex) "best" algorithm that you're having trouble implementing, you can open a separate question about how to get that sort of functionality working.